# How to access data in MongoDB depending on variables in routes?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm modifying a flashcard application that is currently set up to pull questions, hints and answers from a JSON file. I want to instead pull all of this information from a Mongo database.

I have a database called 'flashcards' and a collection called 'cards' already set up locally in MongoDB. The 'cards' collection already has five documents in it - each holding one question, a hint and an answer.

I have a route set up like this: `localhost:5000/${id}?side=${question/answer}` and I want to populate that with an id and either question or answer to display a question or answer based on the id from an associated document in my 'cards' collection in Mongo.

Giving each question an id while pulling from the JSON was easy, you just set up a variable that would require the JSON file and then you can access each element with dot notation or bracket notation. i.e.:

```
const cards = require('./data/flashcardData.json');
```

The general format looks like:

```
cards[id][side];
```

A specific example grabbing the first card and the question side:

```
cards[0][question];
```

JSON for reference:

```
{

"data": {

"title": "JavaScript Flashcards",
"cards": [
  {
    "question": "What language are Express apps written in?",
    "hint": "It starts with a \"J\"",
    "answer": "JavaScript"
  },
  {
    "question": "What is one way a website can store data in a user's browser?",
    "hint": "They are delicious with milk",
    "answer": "Cookies"
  },
  {
    "question": "What is a common way to shorten the response object's name inside middleware?",
    "hint": "It has the same abbreviation as \"resolution\"",
    "answer": "res"
  },
  {
    "question": "How many different values can booleans have?",
    "hint": "Think: binary",
    "answer": "2"
  },
  {
    "question": "Which HTML element can contain JavaScript?",
    "hint": "It starts with an \"s\"",
    "answer": "<script>"
  }
]
  }
}
```

Here is what the 'cards' collection in the 'flashcards' database looks like with the same information as above:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a8b3084c926c61f9f90b61a"),
  "question": "What language are Express apps written in?",
  "hint": "It starts with a \"J\" ",
  "answer": "Javascript"
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a8b31eac5fcfe1fc032ceda"),
  "question": "What is one way a website can store data in a user's browser?",
  "hint": "They are delicious with milk",
  "answer": "Cookies"
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a8b31eac5fcfe1fc032cedb"),
  "question": "What is a common way to shorten the response object's name inside middleware?",
  "hint": "It has the same abbreviation as \"resolution\" ",
  "answer": "res"
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a8b31eac5fcfe1fc032cedc"),
  "question": "How many different values can booleans have?",
  "hint": "Think binary",
  "answer": "2"
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a8b3264e122b41fce2fbcbd"),
  "question": "Which HTML element can contain JavaScript?",
  "hint": "It starts with an \"s\" ",
  "answer": "<script>"
}
```

How do I replicate what was happening before but with Mongo?